# Replace MacBook screen with an external display

Tags: mac, macbook, osx-mountain-lion

I have a unibody macbook running OSX 10.8. I wondered how feasible it would be to use an external monitor instead of the built-in display. **I am *not* talking about plugging in a 2nd monitor** (this is possible and I do already), but making the Macbook think an external display *is* the built-in laptop display. So I can maybe have two external screens and not use the built-in small, low-res screen at all.

Is it a case of getting the right adapter and any monitor should work, or is there more to it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do exactly what you're asking, but if you use clamshell mode (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3131) by waking your laptop while closed (and plugged in, via an external mouse), the laptop display will stay disabled, and I assume both external displays will stay enabled. I've only tested this with one external though.